# batch search for files and move them

Tags: search, batch-file, copy

I have a batch file that is searching for PST files,creating a **.txt** file with the location of the searched files, then creating a folder in the Documents dir.
What I want to do is to copy the PST files to the new dir in the Documents dir.
Problem is I cant get the PST's to copy to the new dir?? 
Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

The **.bat** look like this;

```
dir C:\*.pst /s /b > %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\pstFileLocation.txt
md %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Refresh_PST
for /F "tokens=3" %%v in ('pstFileLocation.txt') do copy "%i" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Refresh_PST"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are reading the text file. You are using `tokens=3` which means you are trying to read the 3rd item in each line (by default items are separated by a space) and there is most likely not a 3rd item if they are just file paths.

You are also trying to copy the variable `%i` which doesn't exist.

You can fix the the token issue using `tokens=*` to read the whole line as one item, but it would be easier and quicker to just do this

```
md "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Refresh_PST"
for /r C:\ %%a in (*.pst) do copy "%%a" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Refresh_PST"
```

Which saves the need for exporting the files to a list and then reading them back.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the files are locked by Outlook. Try to stop outlook before executing the batch.

Comment: The PSTs are not imported into Outlook as yet.